# Show that if the prime $p$ divides $|G|$, then $|X|$ is divisible by $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Question :

Let $p$ be a prime number that divides the order of the finite group $G$. Let $X$ = $\bigcup_{P \in Syl_p(G)}P$. Show that $|X|$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: We know that $X$ is the subset of $G$ consisting the element whose order is of the form $p^a$ . So $X$ is a subgroup if  o$(ab^{-1})$ is of the form $p^a$, then $|X|$ is divisible by p

Comment: Is $X$ is the set of all the sylow subgroups of $G$ or $X$ is the union of all sylow $p-$sylow subgroups of $G$ for a particular prime $p$?

Comment: In the above question, the set $X$ seems to be the set of all sylow subgroups of $G$. If this is the case, $p$ may not divide $|X|$. An example would be $S_3$, here $|X|=4$ and 3 does not divide 4.

Comment: I think that $X$ is the union of the Sylow $p$-subgroups.  This is just the set of elements of $p$-power order in $G$.  In this case, the result is true, while it is not if $X$ is the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups, whose cardinality is certainly not divisible by $p$.

Comment: X is the union of the Sylow p-subgroups

Comment: You need to to start the question with the sentence "Let $p$ be a prime number". Otherwise the symbol $p$ is undefined in your definition of $X$. Note that $X$ is not usually a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @user120386. The set $X$ is not, in general, a subgroup of $G$, so I think you are on the wrong track. Hint: pick a Sylow $p$-subgroup $P$ of $G$, and let it act on $X$ by conjugation. Write $X$ as a disjoint union of the set $F$ of fixed points and the other non-trivial orbits. The length of each non-trivial orbit is a power of $p$, and $F$ is a subgroup with order divisible by $p$, because $P$ has non-trivial centre.

Comment: @Derek Holt. I don't think I can vote with you, but I agree it is kind of interesting. I was annoyed that it got closed while typing my answer (not easy on a phone! :-), and couldn't post it.

Comment: @DerekHolt. I also thought of the inclusion-exclusion idea, but I could not see how to deal with terms of the alternating sum possibly involving trivial intersections.  Can you show that they always contribute something divisible by $p$?

Comment: @James No, I don't see exactly how to deal with trivial intersections, so I have deleted that comment! Something equally annoying happened to me once. I had typed a lengthy answer and then discovered that the poster meanwhile had deleted the question. I think that $F$ in your solution is equal to the centre of $P$.

Comment: The proof relies on analyzing a fixed Sylow $p$-subgroup acting by conjugation on *all* the Sylow $p$-subgroups and the facts that (1) if $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $P \in Syl_p(G)$, then $H \cap C_G(P)=H\cap Z(P)$ and (2) the center of a non-trivial $p$-group is non-trivial.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant "on the union of *all* the Sylow $p$-subgroups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Lemma** Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime divding $|G|$. Let $H$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $P \in Syl_p(G)$. Then $H \cap C_G(P)=H\cap Z(P)$.

**Proof** It is clear that $H \cap Z(P) \subseteq C_H(P)=H \cap C_G(P)$. Conversely, observe that $C_H(P)$ is a $p$-subgroup (it is a subgroup of $H$!) and it normalizes (even centralizes) $P$. So $C_H(P)P$ is a $p$-subgroup containing $P$, and since $P$ is Sylow, this can only be the case if $C_H(P)P=P$, that is $C_H(P) \subseteq P$. So $C_H(P) \subseteq C_G(P) \cap P=C_P(P)=Z(P)$ and of course $C_H(P) \subseteq H$.

**Proposition** Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime divding $|G|$. Let $X=\bigcup_{P \in Syl_p(G)}P$. Then $|X| \equiv 0$ mod $p$.

**Proof** Let $S \in Syl_p(G)$ and let $S$ act on $X$ by conjugation. Let $Y=\{x \in X: s^{-1}xs=x$ for all $s \in S\}$, the set of fixed points under the action. By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem and the fact that $S$ is a $p$-group, it is evident that $|X| \equiv |Y|$ mod $p$. Let us analyze the set $Y$ by applying the Lemma. $Y$ is the set of elements of $X$ that centralize $S$:
$$Y=C_X(S)= X \cap C_G(S) = \bigcup _{P \in Syl_p(G)}(P \cap C_G(S))= \bigcup _{P \in Syl_p(G)}(P \cap Z(S)) = X \cap Z(S) \subseteq Z(S).$$But obviously $Z(S) \subseteq Y$, and we conclude $Y=Z(S)$. Since $S$ is a non-trivial $p$-group, $Z(S)$ is non-trivial, in particular $|Y|=|Z(S)| \equiv 0$ mod $p$, so $p | |X|$.

Comment: @ Nicky Hekster : Please clear me the definition of Y and orbit stablizer theorem says that $|G| = |Stab(x)| |orb(x)|$, How do you write that $|X| \equiv |Y| mod p $

Comment: @user120386 $S$ acts on the set $X$ by conjugation. Because of this action $X$ will be partitioned in orbits: for each $x \in X$, $orb(x)=\{s^{-1}xs: s \in S\}$. Some of these orbits have size $1$ (namely those for which $s^{-1}xs=x$ for all $s \in S$, and this defines the set $Y$) and the other orbits have a size large than $1$, but dividing the order of the acting group $S$ (this follows from the O-S Theorem). These last orbits have a size $p^k$, with $k \gt0$. So we have a disjoint union $X=\bigcup_{x \in Y} \{x\} \cup \bigcup_{x' \notin Y}orb(x')$. This leads to $|X| \equiv |Y|$ mod $p$.

Comment: @ Nicky Hekster : Thank you sir